# How to implement custom validator in generic validator class angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, custom-validators

I am trying implement custom validator into generic validator class, Basically I am aware of that to write normal custom validator in suppurate class but here facing a bit confusion to write in generic validator class. If any one knows please help me out.

Here is my generic-validator.ts file

```js
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

// Generic validator for Reactive forms
// Implemented as a class, not a service, so it can retain state for multiple forms.
export class GenericValidator {

    // Provide the set of valid validation messages
    // Stucture:
    // controlName1: {
    //     validationRuleName1: 'Validation Message.',
    //     validationRuleName2: 'Validation Message.'
    // },
    // controlName2: {
    //     validationRuleName1: 'Validation Message.',
    //     validationRuleName2: 'Validation Message.'
    // }
    constructor(private validationMessages: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string } }) {

    }

    // Processes each control within a FormGroup
    // And returns a set of validation messages to display
    // Structure
    // controlName1: 'Validation Message.',
    // controlName2: 'Validation Message.'
    processMessages(container: FormGroup): { [key: string]: string } {
        let messages = {};
        for (let controlKey in container.controls) {
            if (container.controls.hasOwnProperty(controlKey)) {
                let c = container.controls[controlKey];
                // If it is a FormGroup, process its child controls.
                if (c instanceof FormGroup) {
                    let childMessages = this.processMessages(c);
                    Object.assign(messages, childMessages);
                } else {
                    // Only validate if there are validation messages for the control
                    if (this.validationMessages[controlKey]) {
                        messages[controlKey] = '';
                        if ((c.dirty || c.touched) &&
                            c.errors) {
                            for (let messageKey in c.errors) {
                                if (c.errors.hasOwnProperty(messageKey) &&
                                    this.validationMessages[controlKey][messageKey]) {
                                    messages[controlKey] += this.validationMessages[controlKey][messageKey];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Here these are my parameters for custom validator
i.e say : '22,3333,4,555,66' , [2,5] 
first one is comma separated string ... which might have entries of 2 or 5 long
Here the condition is each comma suppurated string must be >2.

Comment: That code looks familiar! :-) If you look at the github repo that contains this code, you'll see that you don't add the custom validator here. Rather you add it in its own file (number.validator.ts is the custom validator in the example provided).

Comment: @DeborahK Yeah find it, Thank you so much. I have followed your plural site videos, your explanation is fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I write custom validators it is typically to use with reactive forms. My custom validators are in a class that extends Validators from @angular/forms module. 
With this, you return null if the validation is good, and an object if it's bad.The following checks for invalid characters.

```
import { FormControl, Validators, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

// setup simple regex for white listed characters
const validCharacters = /[^\s\w,.:&\/()+%'`@-]/;

// create your class that extends the angular validator class
export class CustomValidators extends Validators {

 // create a static method for your validation
 static invalidateCharacters(control: FormControl) {

    // first check if the control has a value
    if (control.value && control.value.length > 0) {

      // match the control value against the regular expression
      const matches = control.value.match(invalidCharacters);

      // if there are matches return an object, else return null.
      return matches && matches.length ? { invalid_characters: matches } : null;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Make a FormErrorService that builds up your error message:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable()
export class FormErrorService {

  // return list of error messages
  public validationMessages() {
    const messages = {
      required: 'This field is required',
      email: 'This email address is invalid',
      is1980OrLater: 'Please enter a date that is after 01/01/1980.',
      maxDateFailed: (failText: string) => {
        return failText;
      },
      minDateFailed: (failText: string) => {
        return failText;
      },
      invalid_characters: (matches: any[]) => {

        let matchedCharacters = matches;

        matchedCharacters = matchedCharacters.reduce((characterString, character, index) => {
          let string = characterString;
          string += character;

          if (matchedCharacters.length !== index + 1) {
            string += ', ';
          }

          return string;
        }, '');

        return `These characters are not allowed: ${matchedCharacters}`;
      },
    };

    return messages;
  }

  // Validate form instance
  // check_dirty true will only emit errors if the field is touched
  // check_dirty false will check all fields independent of
  // being touched or not. Use this as the last check before submitting
  public validateForm(formToValidate: FormGroup, formErrors: any, checkDirty?: boolean) {
    const form = formToValidate;

    for (const field in formErrors) {
      if (field) {
        formErrors[field] = '';
        const control = form.get(field);

        const messages = this.validationMessages();
        if (control && !control.valid) {
          if (!checkDirty || (control.dirty || control.touched)) {
            for (const key in control.errors) {
              if (key && key !== 'invalid_characters') {
                formErrors[field] = formErrors[field] || messages[key];
              } else {
                formErrors[field] = formErrors[field] || messages[key](control.errors[key]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return formErrors;
  }
}
```

Where you're building the form in your comopnent:

```
    import {CustomValidators} from 'filepath';
    import {FormErrorService} from 'formerrorservicepath';
    myFormGroup: FormGroup;
    public formErrors = {
    myInput: ''
  };
  formErrors = [];
  constructor(
    public formErrorService: FormErrorService
  ) {}
    // then in your ngOnInit 
    this.myFormGroup = new FormGroup({});
    this.myFormGroup.addControl('myInput', new FormControl());
    this.myFormGroup.get('myInput').setValidators(Validators.compose([CustomValidators.invalidCharacters]);

this.myFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
      this.formErrors = [];
        this.formErrors = this.formErrorService.validateForm(
          this.myFormGroup,
          this.formErrors,
          true
        );
      })
```

Now in your HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
<div>
<input type="text" formControlName="myInput"/>
<p *ngFor="let error of formErrors">
{{error}}
</p>
<button type="button" [diabled]="!myFormGroup.valid">Action Button</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out a framework called **ts.validator.fluent**. Generic object validation. Fluent rules.

https://github.com/VeritasSoftware/ts.validator

**NPM Package**:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts.validator.fluent

There is also an **Angular 6 CLI app** to demo the framework:

https://github.com/VeritasSoftware/ts-validator-app-angular6

Here is an example of how your TypeScript models can be validated using the framework:

```
/* Install npm package ts.validator.fluent and then import like below */
import { IValidator, Validator, ValidationResult } from 'ts.validator.fluent/dist';

/*TypeScript model*/
class Person {
   Name: string;
}

/* Validation rules */
var validatePersonRules = (validator: IValidator<Person>) : ValidationResult => {
   return validator
       .NotEmpty(m => m.Name, "Name cannot be empty")
   .ToResult();
};

/* Populate model */
var person = new Person();
person.Name = "John Doe";

/* Validate model */
/* Sync */
var validationResult = new Validator(person).Validate(validatePersonRules);
/* Async */
var validationResult = await new Validator(person).ValidateAsync(validatePersonRules);
```